# TinyMCE iFrame isn't using parent's theme css

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, tinymce

I'm implementing tinymce editor, it creates an iframe with head and body. To insert my site's css I just use the `content_css : "path/to/css/mysite.css"` in the init() for the tinymce, but that for some reason isn't working, it's not being reflected on the iframe, is there any possibility to make it work?

The editor is working but without my site's css styles.

Btw I'm using the latest TinyMCE version (4.0.12)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Official documentation give some pretty good advice on how to use content_css, just read here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:content_css
If you need futher help, can you tell me che full path of the css file and the page loaded inside iframe full path?

Comment: Thanks for replying HypeZ, i found the error... the site has selectors, and so.. whenever i try to use it in the iframe, it won't get applied since selectors doesn't exist in there... that's why. Thanks